# Erlang illegal pattern while working with list of records

Tags: erlang

I am trying to write simple address book in Erlang. I have started with:

```
-record(entry, {name, surname, phone, email}).

createAdressBook() -> [].

addContact(Name, Surname, AdressBook) ->
  case isAlready(Name, Surname, AdressBook) of
    false -> [#entry{name = Name, surname = Surname}|AdressBook];
    _ -> {error, "This entry already exists"}
  end.

isAlready(_, _, []) -> false;
isAlready(Name, Surname, [#entry{name = Name, surname = Surname}|_]) -> true;
isAlready(Name, Surname, [_|T]) -> isAlready(Name, Surname, T).
```

However, after a while, I decided that I'd like to keep name and surname together. After changing the code into following it raises a compilation error (illegal pattern in the second line of new isAlready/3.

```
-record(entry, {person, phone, email}).

createAdressBook() -> [].

addContact(Name, Surname, AdressBook) ->
  case isAlready(Name, Surname, AdressBook) of
    false -> [#entry{person = Name ++ " " ++ Surname}|AdressBook];
    _ -> {error, "This entry already exists"}
  end.

isAlready(_, _, []) -> false;
isAlready(Name, Surname, [#entry{person = Name ++ " " ++ Surname}|_]) -> true;
isAlready(Name, Surname, [_|T]) -> isAlready(Name, Surname, T).
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the proper why to check if `string1 + " " + string2` is the head of the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to perform an operation in the function head, not just match when you use `++`. So that won't work. Instead, use the opportunity in the calling function to create your `Person` value just once, and use it consistently from there:

```
-record(entry, {person, phone, email}).

createAdressBook() -> [].

add_contact(Name, Surname, AdressBook) ->
  Person = Name ++ " " ++ Surname,
  case is_already(Person, AdressBook) of
    false -> [#entry{person = Person}|AdressBook];
    _ -> {error, "This entry already exists"}
  end.

is_already(_, []) -> false;
is_already(Person, [#entry{person = Person}|_]) -> true;
is_already(Person, [_|T]) -> is_already(Person, T).
```

Alternately, you can use a property of records and tuple indexes to use a search function instead of writing your own:

```
is_already(Person, AddressBook) ->
    case lists:keyfind(Person, #entry.person, AddressBook) of
        #entry{} -> true;
        false    -> false
    end.
```

As a style note -- you notice I changed the function names from `isAlready` to `is_already`. In Erlang upper case words have a special meaning, and to prevent confusion we simply use all_lower_and_underscores for function names, and AllUpperCamelCase for variables.

Comment: I decided to use my solution because it avoids using concatenation, but I marked yours as accepted as you solved the problem why ++ didn't work in pattern matching. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Just before ***zxq9*** posted his answer I had found another solution is to keep name and surname as the tuple inside the record's person field.

```
-record(entry, {person, phone, email}).

createAdressBook() -> [].

addContact(Name, Surname, AdressBook) ->
  case isAlready(Name, Surname, AdressBook) of
    false -> [#entry{person = {Name, Surname}}|AdressBook];
    _ -> {error, "This entry already exists"}
  end.

isAlready(_, _, []) -> false;
isAlready(Name, Surname, [#entry{person = {Name, Surname}}|_]) -> true;
isAlready(Name, Surname, [_|T]) -> isAlready(Name, Surname, T).
```

Comment: Indeed! This is probably a better all-around solution anyway, because you avoid massaging data internally. Its a point of architecture, not matching technique in this case, of course, but the only place I would want to actually join them together into a single string is when you are presenting output to the user or another system expecting formatted data.

Answer (score 2):

when pattern matching wiht ++, the heading element must be known when compiling.
For example,

```
TitledName = "Mr. Black",
"Mr. "++LastName= TitledName
```

It is like:

```
[$M, $r, $., $\s|LastName]= TitledName.
```